# Convert WSDL/XSD to java class for Android Application

Tags: java, android, eclipse

What is the preferred method for auto generating a java class using a provided WSDL/XSD?

My plan is to use the generated class to create the necessary class objects in java that will get sent to a RESTful web service as a required parameters. I'd like to simplify the process to prevent serialization/deserialization issues. I can successfully call the target RESTful web service now and pass simple strings but not class objects yet.  I'm not convinced JAXB or WSDL2Java are good options for android applications.

I am using Java ADT v21.0.1.xxx, apache.http.client.http, and a windows XP dev box. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Newbie Java/Android developer,
James

Comment: this java code generation (xsd->java) happens at build-time, not run-time right? so why do you think JAXB is not good for android appl? I am just curious, I have no experience about programming in android.

Comment: My understanding is JAXB leaves a heavy footprint for mobile android applications.  I've used a tool in a different development platform that generates a code class file that can be added to the project without a dependency to additional libraries.  I will still consider JAXB but checking for a better option.  Thanks!

Comment: I went ahead and used SimpleXML framework.  I wasn't crazy about doing manually building the classes with annotations but it worked for the simple processes I am using.